# New to Javascript, need help with HTML5 audio "playlist"

Tags: javascript, iphone, html, audio, playlist

im trying to create a sort of playlist feature that will work on the iPhone using a combination of HTML5 and javascript.  I'm very new to the platform and I was hoping maybe someone here could help me identify the problem with my code.  The first song properly autoplays, but when it ends the next one does not load and play.  The javascript code for my site is provided below, thanks in advance.  (my apologies if this code is terribly messed up, i assembled this from what iv learned and what i could find different places online)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var songname="Bottoms Up";
var counter=1;
var totalsongs=3;
while (counter<=totalsongs-1) {
document.write(<h2>songname</h2>);
switch (counter) {
case 1:
var nextSong="audio/Hey.mp3";
var audioPlayer=document.getElementById('audioPlayer');
audioPlayer.onend = function() {
audioPlayer.src = nextSong;
songname="Hey";
counter=(counter+1);
if(counter>totalsongs-1) {
counter=1;
    } //if close
    } //onend function close
case 2:
var nextSong="audio/I Like It.mp3";
var audioPlayer=document.getElementById('audioPlayer');
audioPlayer.onend = function() {
audioPlayer.src = nextSong;
songname="I Like It";
counter=(counter+1);
if(counter>totalsongs-1) {
counter=1;
    } //if close
    } //onend function close
} //switch close
} //while close
</script>
<center><audio src="audio/Bottoms Up.mp3" autoplay controls /></center>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few things:

Give the `audio` element an id:

```
<audio src="audio/Bottoms Up.mp3" autoplay controls id="audioPlayer" /></center>
```

Use arrays instead of many variables:

```
var songs=({{"title": "First title","filename":"firstfile.mp3"},
        {"title": "Second title","filename":"secondfile.mp3"}});
```

Listen for the event `ended` like this:

```
document.getElementById("audioPlayer").addEventListener("ended", nextSong, false);
```

And put the script in the `<head>` element.

Comment: sorry one last question, does the event listener go in the body or the head? I haven't used one before now.

Answer (score 0):

```
var audioPlayer=document.getElementById('audioPlayer');
```

… will error, since the element doesn't have an id.

Comment: oh, I had found this done with videoPlayer elsewhere and assumed the naming would be the same, is there an online resource i should consult to find the names for such things?

Comment: The video player would have still needed an id. I suggest reading the section "JavaScript core skills" at http://dev.opera.com/articles/view/1-introduction-to-the-web-standards-cur/#toc

Comment: oh now I understand what the other person did, and I'll check out that link thanks, I had just been working my way through the w3schools javascript guide